# Open (alert)dialog by clicking tab from notification drag-down

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have succesfully implemented gcm from samples and can receive a notification message but when I drag-down from the bar, a part of the text appears in a tab.

I can not figure out how to open a (alert)dialog when clicking on the tab and show the whole message.

Anyone?
Thanks from Holland!

```
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
String ticker=arg1.getExtras().getString("ticker");
String subject=arg1.getExtras().getString("subject");
String message=arg1.getExtras().getString("message");

Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) arg0.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(1000);

String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence tickerText = ticker;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = subject;
CharSequence contentText = message;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
final int HELLO_ID = 1;
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PendingIntent` needs to be something the SystemUI can start from outside your package, so make sure that class is declared in your manifest.

More information can be found in the [Notifications guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse).